# How do i make power gage using opengl?

Tags: opengl

i'm making a simple tank shooting program.

it is opengl 3d game and has angle, power gauge. i will use this factor to calculate spot to drop missile.

the space bar that control power gauge and left , right , up , down key will be used for controlling angle.

so i want to make power gauge bar and angle form like below image

[image]

but I don't know how i dock this form in opengl .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "dock" a form in OpenGL. There are two choices: Either you draw the GUI part with normal OpenGL commands (which is relatively easy and straightforward), or you create a second window which hosts the form (or a child window if your Window manager supports that). For example, under Windows this works pretty trivially. I advise against it, however, since directly drawing the GUI in OpenGL is straightforward and hardware-accelerated.

Drawing your GUI in OpenGL can be done using one of the many available GUI libraries, or you can probably just hand-code the few elements that you need. This may be as fast as first figuring out how another framework is used.
A power bar is basically a rectangle (maybe with a gradient or texture), and the little wedges are just textured point sprites. The main "form" background can likewise be drawn with just a single textured quad. The angle gauges would be a few lines drawn over the background, again no big challenge.

The most "challenging" bit is drawing dynamic text (like "Delay 720" in the screenshot) because quality text involves a bit more than just tossing a simple textured rectangle on screen, you will for example want to do proper kerning so it looks good.
Generally, though, you would still typically use textured quads since it's the fastest solution (optionally with a distance field texture). For bitmap fonts, numerous readily available libraries (and content creation tools, e.g. [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)) exist, too.

Comment: however, how do i power bar and angle don't move if camera position is changed?

Comment: @dskim reset view and projection matrices to identity, aka don't put them in the game world but draw them directly on as viewport coordinates

Comment: Either this (then you must think in normalized coordinates, that is -1 to +1), or use `glOrtho` with appropriate parameters, if you prefer to think in "pixels". In the end, it is the same thing. Only once you do the scaling beforehand, and in the other case OpenGL does it.

Comment: @Damon Ok. I understood what you say. It really helps me . thank you !